# Ajax call not returning response from c# code

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Here is my jquery code

```
var ajaxUrl = "AjaxCallHandler.aspx";
function _init_Chart() {

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",        //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
    url: ajaxUrl,       // Location of the service
    data: "OpCode=GetCallAverageReportForGraph&Parms=DeptId^17~Month^10~Year^2012",         //Data sent to server
    contentType: "",    // content type sent to server
    dataType: "string",     //Expected data format from server
    processdata: true,  //True or False
    success: function (responseString) {//On Successful service call
        alert(responseString);
    }
});

return false;
```

}

Here is my c# code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string responseMessage = "";
        string status = "SUCCESS";
        try
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["OpCode"] == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid Request, OpCode missing.");
            }
            string operationRequested = Request.QueryString["OpCode"];
            string Params = Request.QueryString["Parms"];
            switch (operationRequested)
            {
                case "GetCallAverageReportForGraph":
                    responseMessage = GetCallAverageReportForGraph(Params);
                    break;
                case "GetCallAverageReportDetails":
                    responseMessage = GetCallAverageReportDetails(Params);
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            status = "EXCEPTION";
            responseMessage = exp.Message;
        }
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.Write(responseMessage);
    }
```

I tried putting a breakpoint in the c# code. It is writing `Response.Write` from c# code but I'm unable to receive the response in jquery code. Can any one point out the issue?

Comment: Try removing Response.ClearHeaders() and ClearContent() lines and check

Comment: add an error callback to see if something wrong is happening in the call.

Comment: Try adding an error handler to the Ajax call and see if there's any error and make sure that responseMessage has a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the **data type string to html** or leave it empty for default type

Refer http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @jade. This answer will not give ajax as far as I can see. read my answer.

Comment: @gdoron he simply calling a page and not a page method. So i answered

Comment: But @jade. should be aware that this won't be a true ajax, it will load the full page. **This is not how you do ajax calls!**

Comment: @gdoron i'll do dat.Thnks for answers anywaz

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of missing things in your code.

You need to a static method marked with the attribute `WebMethod`:

```
[WebMethod]
public static RetrunValue Foo()
{
    ...
}
```

The data must be in *json* format in asp.net.

[You should read this article](http://encosia.com/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/)

Comment: @jade You must avoid to use a full page that way, ether make a webmethod, ether a web handler. And also you need to clarify what is the real issue, the page is called ? do you make debug ?

Comment: @jade. From what I've seen when I used ajax to asp.net, you need to do all the things I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Write the code in code behid in this way.

```
Response.Clear();
        Response.Write("Your response in string");
        Response.End();
```

Please not that if your response is in HTML you have to pass the string in Response.Write("Your String"), If your response is in Json Format write your code like this.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(List<object> of your code);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Write(json);
        Response.End();
```

Comment: which library to use for JsonConvert

Comment: you have to use "Newtonsoft.Json" dll.