# jquery+AJAX+c# causing page load

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i'm trying to make an Ajax call but its causing page load
Here is my jquery code

```
    var ajaxUrl = "AjaxCallHandler.aspx";
function _init_Chart() {

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",        //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
    url: ajaxUrl,       // Location of the service
    data: "OpCode=GetCallAverageReportForGraph&Parms=DeptId^17~Month^10~Year^2012",         //Data sent to server
    contentType: "",    // content type sent to server
    dataType: "string",     //Expected data format from server
    processdata: true,  //True or False
    success: function (responseString) {//On Successful service call
        alert(responseString);
    }
});

return false;
}
```

And here is my AjaxCallHandler.aspx.cs c# code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string responseMessage = "";
    string status = "SUCCESS";
    try
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["OpCode"] == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid Request, OpCode missing.");
        }
        string operationRequested = Request.QueryString["OpCode"];
        string Params = Request.QueryString["Parms"];
        switch (operationRequested)
        {
            case "GetCallAverageReportForGraph":
                responseMessage = GetCallAverageReportForGraph(Params);
                break;
            case "GetCallAverageReportDetails":
                responseMessage = GetCallAverageReportDetails(Params);
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        status = "EXCEPTION";
        responseMessage = exp.Message;
    }
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.Write(responseMessage);
}
```

I dont know why this thing is causing a page load.i'm new to jquery AJAX but when i tried this with  javascript AJAX it was working fine without any page load.

Comment: you must avoid to call a full aspx page from ajax, especial that way, just to run the page_load and make all that clear headers. Use ether a handler, ether webservice.

Comment: Same code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414683/ajax-call-not-returning-response-from-c-sharp-code  other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that is the code behind for your AjaxCallHandler.aspx?

If so, your AJAX call is essentially just loading the results of that page just like you would if you were hitting it with a browser window (i.e. a GET).

Most of the time when you want to do an AJAX request, you would be calling it against an MVC function that returns a JSONResult ActionResult or a Web Service (.asmx) for example.

Since you're just hitting a regular web page, it will always do a Page_Load event on that page's code behind.

Comment: is this the case with jquery AJAX.I'm asking this coz i was earlier using javascript AJAX and was calling a aspx page only and it was working fine without any page load.Any particular reason for this kinda behaviour?

Comment: The requested page might have been cached. Both HTTP and ASP.NET have several layers of caching. In that case the result of the handler would have been retrieved from the cache, without calling its aspx handler at all.

Comment: The behaviour should be the same.  IIS shouldn't be concerned with whom is making the GET request when it is executing its event stack

Comment: @jade I would add, as Honza has pointed out, if you're using IE for your testing, it can do some funky things with AJAX caching you should be aware of which may explain why you are not seeing your refresh consistently.

Comment: cache was the issue...setting cache: false to ajax call resolved the issue